# How can I incorporate net tcp bindings into a web api environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, tcp

I have a asp.net web api application implemented in c#. I'm using an ApiController which is working perfectly.

The controller processes a JSON object (wrapped in HTML).

I know would like to implement the exact same logic, but the request will not be a JSON wrapped HTML request, but a raw tcp socket request of JSON data.

What is the best approach to implementing this functionality?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a Windows service, but why would you want to duplicate that functionality when if you have access to tcp/ip you can just make that a Web request as well?

Comment: I only have control over the server. The client communication is beyond my control. Clients communicate with the server using http wrapped json and raw tcp socket json. I'm trying to figure out the best approach to get access to and then process the raw tcp socket request without duplicating the work I've done using web api. A windows service.... implementing what technology? tcp.net? That seems only appropriate for wcf to wcf communication. TcpListener? Possible, but it seems I have so build an entire server. I'm thinking there should be an out-of-the-box solution. But I can't seem to find it

Comment: I'm afraid it's outside of my skillset. The last time I looked into something like this was about 8 years ago or so when I was trying to create an app for an Onkyo receiver I had that was an early adopter of network technology. It didn't work out because the communications were encrypted; beyond that I don't remember much. I think TcpListener sounds right, or you might want to see if looking into sockets reveals any info. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx I'm going to follow this thread; I'm interested to know as well.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with Microsoft's example of an async socket server. My primary concern is scalability, but I'll cross that bridge when I get to it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-an-asynchronous-server-socket